# Storing the selection changed behaviour of Word bookmark in XML format

Tags: xml, ms-word, vsto, customtaskpane

I am attempting to put together a Word application using VSTO that, amongst other things would contain bookmarks that, when clicked, display information in a custom task pane.

I would like to be able to export this document into XML, but if you simply save it in this format, the "pop up" behaviour is lost. I am intending to write an "export to XML" piece of functionality but I'm wondering if it is possible to persist this "on click" behaviour into the XML format.

I've tried looking through various other sites already but I'm getting a bit lost and was hoping someone here could help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this:

- **Application.XMLSelectionChange Event:**
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221360(v=office.12).aspx